# Why doesn't "git log -‌- foo" work for deleted file foo?

Tags: git, git-log

My repository underwent changes such as:

1. ...some unrelated commits...
2. Commit new file `foo` with 100 lines of content
3. ...intervening commits, some of which touch `foo`...
4. Insert the contents of `foo` at the top of an existing file `bar` and `git rm foo` in the same commit
5. ...more unrelated commits...

Now I want to see the log of deleted file `foo`.  Everything I've read, including on SO, says I should be able to `git log -- foo`, but that command produces no output.

If I find the commit that includes deleting `foo` I can `git log 1234abcd -- foo` and see its log, so I think my path to `foo` isn't the problem.  Also note that `git merge-base HEAD 1234abcd` outputs `1234abcd[...]`, so I think that should prove the commit is reachable from `HEAD`.  Note that there is no file `foo` in my working tree (obvious, since it was deleted).  Using Git 1.7.1.1 on OS X.

Why doesn't `git log -- foo` work for me and how can I fix it?  Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `git log --follow -- foo` or `git log --follow -M -- foo`? (to force renaming detection)

Comment: Crap, I did try `--follow`--but reading `history` I see I had since cd'ed elsewhere when I tried it, making the path invalid.  `git log --follow -- foo` worked when I tried from the right starting point.  I guess Git considered rolling `foo` into `bar` as some kind of rename?

In any case, thank you!  I'll be happy to credit this if you'll repost it as an answer.

Comment: Annoying that `--` gets changed to `—` in the question title...

Answer (score 125):

You want to use the `--follow` option on `git log`, which is described in the man page as:

```
Continue listing the history of a file beyond renames.
```

Effectively, not only does this allow you to see the history of a renamed file, but this also allows you to view the history of a file no longer in the working tree. So the command you should use should look something like:

```
git log --follow -- foo
```

**Update:**

Git 2.9+ has now enabled this by default for all `git diff` and `git log` commands:

> The end-user facing Porcelain level commands in the "git diff" and
>   "git log" family by default enable the rename detection; you can still
>   use "diff.renames" configuration variable to disable this.

Thanks to x-yuri for the heads up!

Comment: It worked for me without the `--follow` part. I just needed to add `--`. I'm running `git-2.9.0`.